Materialised View vs physical table
I'm really getting confused as why to use a materialised view instead of a normal table. if it is because of convinience of writing a complex query, precomputing and storing then we can do the same thing with a table by inserting a new data into a table everyday like how we refresh MV. Am I missing something? Could anyone please explain where and why we should use MV instead of a table?

Performance Considerations. Materialized Views offer a performance edge in such cases. Because they cache the result and store it as a physical table, accessing a Materialized View can be significantly faster than rerunning a complex query. This benefit is pronounced when the data doesn't require frequent updating.

Hi Bart, thanks for your inputs. we can also do the same thing with normal table right, by running the complex query and inserting into a table? so why should we go for MV instead of table?

You are missing the Cache part. The key difference between Views and Materialized Views is that Materialized Views are stored in memory,

Hi Bart, I agree, if we are comparing views with MVs but here I'm comparing MV with a table and want to understand why I should use MV instead of a table or when to use MV
